# Vectorizing a function using numpy vectorize

Tags: python, numpy

I want to vectorize the following function. The arguments are numpy arrays.

```
def euclidean_distance(dl, dr):
    return math.sqrt(((dl - dr) ** 2).sum())
```

I do the following

```
v_u = numpy.vectorize(euclidean_distance)
```

and I am doing the following call

```
v_u(numpy.array([[10, 20, 30], [4, 5, 6]]), numpy.array([1, 2, 3]))
```

What I want is that I get back an array which contains the euclidean distance of `[1, 2, 3]` with `[10, 20, 30], [4, 5, 6]`.

I think I am missing something obvious.

**EDIT:**
The following is the error I get

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

which is obvious that `dl` and `dr` are passed as single elements but not as arrays... 
So I was wondering if somebody could correct it so that it operated on arrays.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your problem? What is the error or unexpected output you get?

Comment: `[1,2,3]`, `[10,20,30]`, `[4,5,6]`, they are 3D coordinates? So you want the distance between `[1,2,3]` and every point in the other array?

Comment: @marshal.ward, yup you are right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need `vectorize` for that?

You can use shape broadcasting and do something like:

```
dist = numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((d1-dr)**2, axis = 1))
```